# What is difference between install desktop-environment and run directly distro?

Tags: desktop-environments, derivatives

My question is what is difference between installing perticular desktop environment on Ubuntu And Using directly that (Default -environmented) distro/flavour of Ubuntu?

Example: Two options:

1. Install `ubuntu-gnome-desktop` or `kubuntu-desktop` or `xubuntu-desktop`etc. (official & recognized derivatives) alternatively on Ubuntu
   (Default -Unity Desktop)
2. Use (Run) perticular distro/flavour `Ubuntu-Gnome` or `Kubuntu` or `Xubuntu` etc.

I want to know is both method working same performance? <s>and which is proper method to use Desktop Environment.</s>

Comment: I think using option 1 results in having (to clean up) your previous derivative's applications and libraries, whereas option 2 is like a clean installation without your previous derivative's applications.

Comment: @saiarcot895 Otherwise it is same?

Comment: Probably. The other difference is that option 1 is better for those who already have Ubuntu (or derivative) installed, while option 2 is for new users or for those doing a clean install.

Comment: @saiarcot895 I am not talking about who have already ubuntu and who want to clean install BUT consider one clean install Ubuntu and then install Desktop-Environment and other clean install directly that distro.

Comment: @user68186: But would option 2 also have the main Ubuntu applications (those that come with the default Ubuntu)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**They are not different**

Suppose you have already installed Ubuntu and want to try Kubuntu. Most of the stuff is already there. Install the Desktop Environment (DE), option 1.

Now you have both. Each DE comes with some default applications. You can use any application in any DE. You can log out of one DE and log back into the other DE. Your files will be in the same place, just the environment will look and work different.

Now suppose you like KDE better and don't like Unity. You have another computer, and you want the KDE on that one. Install Kubuntu directly on the computer. Go for option 2. Kubuntu uses the KDE Desktop Environment, Ubuntu uses Unity by default. But they are both the same distro (Ubuntu).

**Default Applications**

The default applications are different in different DEs. Some DEs have more common default applications than others. For example Unity and Gnome have many common default applications. The default applications in Unity and KDE are somewhat different. If you start with Unity, and install the Kubuntu-desktop, option 1, you will have the default applications of both the DE.

If you go for option 2 and install Kubuntu, you can still install some default applications of Unity if you like them better. For example, you can install Firefox, the default browser in Ubuntu in a fresh Kubuntu installation.

The difference between the flavors are in the set of packages installed. However, all flavors of Ubuntu use the same repository for downloading updates, so the same set of packages is available regardless of which flavor you have installed. New flavors have to go through a process to become a Recognized Flavor.

Reference: [Ubuntu Flavors](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuFlavors)

Hope this helps