# What is the difference between these cinnamon repos?

Tags: cinnamon, mint

In [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/94201/how-do-i-install-the-cinnamon-desktop) it lists three repos for letting you install cinnamon:

- ppa:tsvetko.tsvetkov/cinnamon
- ppa:lestcape/cinnamon
- deb http://packages.linuxmint.com/ qiana main upstream import

I don't care about new features/whizbang but rather whichever is the most stable/least-bugs.

**What are the differences with these repos? Is one of them officially supported for Ubuntu by Canonical?**

---

I am interested in people who know something about software "stability", "robustness", etc based on their experience (or first hand authors of the ppa) with 2 or 3 of these repos. I asked because ["As anybody can create a PPA there's no guarantee for quality or security of a PPA - just like with any other unofficial software source you have to decide yourself if a PPA it's trustworthy or not."](https://askubuntu.com/a/4987/78103)

Comment: None of the repositories is supported by Canonical.

To check the differences in the repositories, download the source code and compare or compare the build recipes.

Comment: Looking quickly at the first two on launchpad: they both look like they are completely produced/published by a single individual or small group (I could be wrong). Where as the linux mint repo has a larger distro/community behind it.

Comment: This is about mint and "quiana"... off topic. This needs to be asked on  http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linux-mint

Comment: Create a repository is not directly relate with create software, in the lestcape ppa case, Cinnamon is directly compiled and installed inside ubuntu from source, i never apply a patch directly to the repository, all patch that i apply to the repository are also applied to the cinnamon master source branch in github. Please feel free to find me in the contributors. https://github.com/linuxmint/Cinnamon/graphs/contributors

Comment: I hope some one can explain here the difference of a distro and a Desktop, because apparently there are a lot of people that think Ubuntu is not Ubuntu if you add a different program or a different Desktop, also if is available in the Ubuntu official repositories for others newest ubuntu versions. http://askubuntu.com/questions/478080/what-is-difference-between-install-desktop-environment-and-run-directly-distro/478095#478095

Comment: @TrevorBoydSmith Talk about it on the official chat [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32504/linux-mint) or the unofficial one [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32292/we-need-linux-mint-on-se).

Answer (score 2):

Yes "stability" and "robustness" with quotes, because there is not any thing perfect in the world. We are not perfect. If you provide "robustness" then you will need to update your software, also applying patch for vulnerabilities, add the compatibility with other software and more things. In some point a patch to your software will not be enough, because the technology never ends. All of this patches are not in the original conception of the software, and as is a modification you will always lose stability in the process.

The principal main problem with mint repository in Ubuntu, could be, have a reference of mint specific software that is not present in ubuntu. This fact could be the cause of the installations of unnecessary packages, also incompatible packages, and as a result breaking of your installation. The mint repository is not aimed to be used in ubuntu.

With the first two repos, the main difference will be that the tsvetko repo can be used for different Ubuntu versions and the lestcape repo is only provided for ubuntu 14.04. I don't compile cinnamon for more ubuntu versions, because this task was done by the Debian mantainers and in my opinion more than a help, this will create incompatibilities and then instabilities.